# TreeTable in Primevue does not show labels

Tags: vue.js, primevue

So i have tree structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "0",
        "label": "some label",
        "children": [
            {
                "key": "0-0",
                "label": "some label",
                "data": "ZG9rdW1lbnQxZmlsZTE="
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "1",
        "label": "some label",
        "children": [
            {
                "key": "1-0",
                "label": "some label",
                "data": "ZG9rdW1lbnQyZGF0YTE="
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I pass this object to TreeTable's value.
The TreeTable is showing two rows and are expandable but it does not show labels, keys or data at all.
Just blank rows with expand buttons.
Any suggestion why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeNode` elements for the `<TreeTable>` component require just `key` and `data` properties, where `data` is an object containing key-values for each column.

Example involving columns for "Name", "Size" and "Type"

```js
[
    {
        key: '0',
        data: {
            name: 'Applications',
            size: '100kb',
            type: 'Folder'
        },
        children: [
            {
                key: '0-0',
                data: {
                    name: 'Vue',
                    size: '25kb',
                    type: 'Folder'
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        key: '0-0-0',
                        data: {
                            name: 'vue.app',
                            size: '10kb',
                            type: 'Application'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        key: '0-0-1',
                        data: {
                            name: 'native.app',
                            size: '10kb',
                            type: 'Application'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        key: '0-0-2',
                        data: {
                            name: 'mobile.app',
                            size: '5kb',
                            type: 'Application'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                key: '0-1',
                data: {
                    name: 'editor.app',
                    size: '25kb',
                    type: 'Application'
                }
            },
            {
                key: '0-2',
                data: {
                    name: 'settings.app',
                    size: '50kb',
                    type: 'Application'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The documentation is really bad at explaining this, and the included code snippets don't show the correct format either, but clicking the links to view the examples in codesandbox or stackblitz will finally show the correct format being used.

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpoqcl?file=/src/service/NodeService.js:3284-3317)